# My 2d array is taking one extra element

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am trying to input 2d array from user, my array size is 6, but I am bale to input 7 elements. What is the error here? can you please also tell me how to input a 2d array from user using single pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2][3] = {0};
    int i=0,j=0,l=0;
    printf("enter 2d");

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d\n",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my output:

```
./input2dusingsinglearray 

enter 2d

1
2
3
4
5
6
7

1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: There is no error in your code (at least not as I can tell). Your code instructs your program to read 6 integers, thus if you write 7 integers (or any number of integers greater than 6) only the first 6 integers will be read. The remaining integers in this case will simply be discarded.

Comment: That is a rather unsexy indentation...

Comment: Does the sexiness of question matters? ;) :P @Chiel

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `\n` in `scanf` (unless you really sure that you should). Change it to `scanf("%d", &a[i][j])`.

Comment: Drop the "\n" newline character from the scanf statement. it will work fine. though the Indentation looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes there is no error but there should be some reason what is that? Can you tell me please? @Frxstrem

Comment: @jeevan if you want your question to be solved, it tends to help to make your code readable :)

Comment: Haha wow thanks @Keltar , hey can you please tell me how to input 2d array using single pointer

Comment: @jeevan what do you mean? Your 2d array is actually unrolled by compiler and have linear memory layout, you can set pointer to first element and index it like any 1D array (but it still have 2*3 elements).

Comment: no no nothing thanks @keltar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `scanf` waiting for an extra intro, change to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[2][3] = {0};
    int i=0,j=0,l=0;

    printf("enter 2d\n");
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also note that a 2d array must be initialized in this way:

```
int a[2][3] = {{0},{0}};
```

Turning your warnings on:

> warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]

Comment: LOL you men never miss a chance eh!

Comment: oooops, no, I'm harmless LOL

Answer (score 2):

Try using `scanf("%d", &a[i][j])` instead of `scanf("%d\n", &a[i][j])`.

Comment: No worries. Actually my answer should have been a comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so :).

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are fine and correct, allow me to add my solution as well

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    size_t rows = 2;
    size_t columns = 3;

    int* matrix = (int *) malloc( rows * columns * sizeof(int));

    printf("insert into 2d matrix[%d][%d]:\n", rows, columns);

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", (matrix + (i * columns) + j));
        }
    }


    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            printf("matrix[%d][%d] => %d\n", i, j, *(matrix + (i * columns) + j));
        }
    }
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

It dynamically allocate memory for 2d array and it can be an elegant solution if you want to pass pointer to a function.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem yesterday and found that when we use extra space or any other thing it wants extra input. Then I've used the scanf function like down below.

```
scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
```